# "Foreign Key" VLOOKUP in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not too learned in Excel functions, so I'm not quite sure how to use a VLOOKUP to achieve my goal.

I have two worksheets in excel, and I need to get referential data from one sheet into another.

In one sheet, it looks like this:

```
Worksheet A
a
a
b
b
b
c
```

In the next table, it looks like this:

```
Worksheet B
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
```

I need to get all the information from Worksheet B to match worksheet A, so it will look like this:

```
Worksheet A
a | 1
a | 1
b | 2
b | 2
b | 2
c | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,SHEETB!A:B,2)
```

A2 is the **value in SHEET A** that you want to look for its corresponding information.
**SheetB!A:B** is **the range** of information in SheetB that you want to copy from
2 is the column number in the range that you want to get information from (1 2 ...)

Comment: Can you explain this function a bit more, like what each part is referencing?